# form element Compatability issues

Tags: html, forms, css, combobox

I have written css for form elements and in mac browser the form elements look too differ as compare to windows broswer and also mac's broswer doesn't take any css to change the look and feel of form element. Is there any css for mac which will change the look of form elements same as it looks in windows browser?

Comment: can you show your html & css or sample screen shots of the issue to help folks understand your question a little more?

Comment: Mac should read CSS the same way as Windows, since it's browser dependant. Altough the **default style** is quite different.

Comment: It's the native UI taking over browser controls. You'll have to use a javascript plugin to have them look similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to help strip browser defaults. You'll need to add rules to stylize everything in a consistent manner, but this will be a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very good and well referenced css package called [**Formalize CSS** - Teach your forms some manners!](http://formalize.me/)  to make the look and feel of your html form elements cross browser and cross os compatibility.